# Two tableView and just one selection with JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I have two tableViews in my application, and I want that just one stays enable per time.

For example I have tableView1 and tableView2

if tableView2 is selected (or focused) then tableView1 clear Selection.

I've tried some codes, but they doesn't seems to work.

```
mainTableView2.focusModelProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1) {
                mainTableView1.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this sample, you've wrongly assigned listener. You've wrote :

```
mainTableView2.focusModelProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1) {
            mainTableView1.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        }
    });
```

This means, that TableView has a strategy of changing *focused item or cell*, which allows to change focus programmaticaly, track focused items, etc... And you add listener on *changing that strategy*, which actually is not changed usually. If you want to track a focused item of table, you should add listeners on properties of that focus model.

What you want should look like this :

```
mainTableView2.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1) {
            mainTableView1.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        }
    });
```

This property (focused property) respond to the focused state of control (blue border - for caspian style, and red border for modena style).

BUT, during evaluation, I've found out, that there is a bug (see comments), so I suggest a workaround for that issue :

```
    scene.focusOwnerProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Node>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Node> ov, Node t, Node t1) {

            if (t1 == table2) {
                table1.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            }
            if (t1 == table1) {
                table2.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            }
        }
    });
```

Paste there any similar logic..

Comment: This solution is correct in theory, but looks like there is a bug

Comment: That is why this idea will not work : http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28491